# Azure Devops, how can I use "Parent" in a query?

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps query builder, one can include the Parent field in a query. What I tried to do is search for User Stories that don't have the Parent field set (discover unparented user stories), but the query errors out saying it wants an integer.

I found alternative ways to find unparented user stories, but that leaves me with this: Is there any way to use the Parent field in a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the Parent field in a query to discover unparented user stories.

Please leave the Parent field `=` empty and you will get the unparented user stories.

[image: get the unparented user stories]

And if the Parent field `<>` empty and you will get the parented user stories.

[image: get the parented user stories]

Comment: Brilliant my friend! I tried this yesterday but I didn't think it worked, and so I went down a more complicated path. This gives me the same result as the more complicated "work items and direct lists" query strategy.